# Escutar textarea, substituir por dados de uma planilha e imprimir em outro textarea, em Vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, vue.js

Tem uma function no sistema do trampo que pega o texto digitado na View (textarea e input), faz a leitura de onde tem {}, que se referem a coluna da planilha que foi upada na View, substitui as informações que estao sendo referidas entre chaves pelas celulas da planilha e imprime uma notificação, atraves do evento @click, da mensagem final com as substituições dos dados da planilha. Espero ter explicado corretamente.
Preciso que esta mensagem seja impressa automaticamente num outro textarea que esteja escutando o que foi digitado nos outros campos com as substituições.
Ou pelo menos, utilizar esta function visualizeMensagem() neste textarea que esteja escutando os eventos.

VUE

```
visualizeMensagem: function () {

                let assuntoFinal = (this.assunto ? this.assunto + '
' : ''),
                    codigo = new RegExp('smsurl.com.br/[a-zA-Z0-9]+', 'g');

                if (SMSDigital['tipoCliente'] == SMSDigital.tipoClienteEnum.smsmkt)
                    assuntoFinal = this.assunto + ': 
';

                let total,
                    mensagem = (assuntoFinal + this.mensagem + (this.assinatura ? '
' + this.assinatura : '')).replace(/\r\n|\r|\n/g, '
').replace(/{reenvio}/ig, '1'),
                    maioresValores = this.maioresValores();

                for (let i in maioresValores) {
                    mensagem = mensagem.replace(new RegExp(`{${i}}`, 'gi'), maioresValores[i]);
                    mensagem = mensagem.replace(new RegExp(`{primeiro.${i}}`, 'gi'), (maioresValores[i] || '').split(' ')[0]);
                }

                let resultado = codigo.exec(mensagem);

                if (resultado)
                    mensagem = mensagem.replace(resultado[0], resultado[0] + Envio.paraCodigo(maioresValores['celular']));

                total = mensagem.replace(/
/g, ' ')/*.replace(/\%/g, '%25')*/.length;

                if (SMSDigital['tipoCliente'] == SMSDigital.tipoClienteEnum.smsmkt)
                    total = total - 2;

                SMSDigital.notifiqueHTML(`${mensagem}

${total} caracteres que serão enviados em ${Envio.totalCreditosCobrados(total - 1, this.flash)} mensagen(s)`);            
        }
```

HTML

```
                            Assunto
                            
                                                               

                            
                            Mensagem
                             

                            Assinatura
                            

                        
 Visualize Mensagem

 {{assunto}}
{{ mensagem }}
{{assinatura}}
```

[image: notificação do texto com as sustituicões]

Comment: Pode usar uma  computed property  https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html

Comment: cara, eu certo!!! utilizei o computed e funfou!!!! vlw meu amigo! muito obrigado!!!!